# how does this page implement the face recognition algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, simplecv

Lately I've been very interested in this subject, for example I found a very interesting page that actually does it and  it does it remarkable well http://www.pictriev.com/

How do they achieve such a grade of accuracy?

Comment: how does this have anything to do with python?

Comment: @raspberry.pi actually I'm looking information with a Python flavor in it, since I'm doing develoment with Python.

Comment: Seems to work about on par with OpenCV as far as recognition is concerned. Funny, I gave it a photo of a pre-teen Chinese girl, and it said she was 20, of indeterminate gender, and looks similar to some black dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like recognition algorithms are part of the field of artificial intelligence, specifically the branch of [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). An algorithm like this could be be implemented in many ways, for instance with [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) which try and simulate brains. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289920/is-there-a-recommended-package-for-machine-learning-in-python) question has a list of Python packages to do with machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

The literature on face recognition is vast and the number of approaches and algorithm is great.

In the webpage you mention, they're actually implemented face detection, not recognition.

There is no way to know exactly which algorithm they implemented. If you're interested in face detection, you can start by reading about the Viola&Jones algorithm.

For information on the problem of face recognition, you can refer to this site: http://www.face-rec.org/